# make sound on segfault signal Manjaro Linux

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, manjaro

i wonder if it is possible to make a sound on my pc if a program segfault.
if it is possible, can somebody explain me how to do it?
PS : i'm under manjaro linux.
Thank's

Comment: You may adjust `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` to use pipe syntax, see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html.